# Self hosting of recaptcha-like system to digitise my uploaded books

Tags: looking-for-a-script, captcha

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA)

> reCAPTCHA is a system ... that uses CAPTCHA to help digitize 
>   the text of books while protecting websites from bots

I have a lot of scanned documents that I'd like to convert, and would like to introduce a captcha on my website, so why not kill two birds with one stone?

The reCAPTCHA project has it's own agenda though focusing on archives of The New York Times and books from Google Books.

Does a similar project exist that I could host and thereby dictate the books/docs that are digitised?

Comment: This question is constructive but off topic.  It is an exact duplicate of a question on Stack Overflow that predates our site.  See this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244179/are-there-open-source-captcha-solutions-available

Comment: @RandomBen I think Craig's looking for a way to use a CAPTCHA-like system to digitise books, not to validate user input (as in that SO question).

Comment: @Craig My advice would be to use Google's own [Optical Character Recognition](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#SpecialFeatures) system to upload your images and convert them to text on the fly ([demo](http://googlecodesamples.com/docs/php/ocr.php) and [more info](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-ocr.html)). A self-hosted CAPTCHA system would be too slow to convert whole books. reCAPTCHA is only employed to use humans to convert unknown words, not whole documents.

Comment: @Nick Correct I'm not looking for a general open source captcha system.

Comment: However if it's open source then you can change the source to use your documents.

Comment: @Nick reCAPTCHA does do whole documents, a word at a time - see http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore

Comment: @Nick Google run regular OCR on the docs and then feeds the words not recognised into reCAPTCHA, to complete the document. I'm looking to achieve the same, but my docs are very poor scans so I won't do the initial OCR. As for how long the digitisation takes this depends on the number of logons/users, I'm not in a rush anyway.

Comment: @paulmorriss The page you linked to says that the books are first scanned and digitised using OCR, then "reCAPTCHA improves the process of digitizing books by sending words that cannot be read by computers to the Web in the form of CAPTCHAs for humans to decipher." I think the whole point is to translate words OCR can't handle.

Comment: @RandomBen Can you explain why this is off topic, it seems acceptable according to the FAQ? If it really would be more suited to another SE site please migrate it rather than closing.

Comment: @paulmorriss I'm all for open source but it's not a requirement of mine. Also note that reCAPTCHA is not open source (not that you said it was).

Comment: @Craig - I re-opened the question.  This might not be the best site for it but I am not sure which one is at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google's [OCR](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#SpecialFeatures) to digitize those books. As for using your own books to translate, there isn't currently third-party software available for that. For added reasoning against this, an excerpt from the CAPTCHA Site;

> Should I Make My Own CAPTCHA?
>
> In general, making your own CAPTCHA script (e.g., using PHP, Perl or .Net) is a bad idea, as there are many failure modes. We recommend that you use a well-tested implementation such as reCAPTCHA.

Further, he [spoke](http://www.ted.com/talks/luis_von_ahn_massive_scale_online_collaboration.html) at a TED conference on the subject of reCAPTCHA. If you do infact intend on making your own, might as well study up.

Comment: The Google OCR link you provided no longer has info on OCR. Do you have an updated link?